# Replacing cell values in pandas dataframe with values from list (vectorized)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization, pandas-apply

I'm trying to do the following:

For each row of column 'A' where a condition in column 'B' is met I'd like to replace the value in column 'A' by the first element of my list 'end' and then delete the first element so that for the next row the previously "second" element in the list is taken.

If I'd do it with a for loop it would look like this, assuming that the condition is that the value of B in the previous row is True (B contains only boolean values):

```
for i in range(1, len(data)-1):
    if data.loc[i, 'B'].shift(-1) == True:
        data.loc[i, 'A'] = end[0]
        del end[0]
```

Since my df is huge I'm searching for a vectorized version, but apparently my approach does not work, it always only takes the first element of the list:

`data['A'][data['B'].shift(-1)== True] = data['A'].apply(lambda x: end.pop(0))`

Any ideas?